# HTTP 400 Error when working with Google API for geocoding

Tags: python, google-maps-api

We are geocoding German place names with Google and have experienced occasional HTTP 400 errors:

[image]

We cannot really figure out what went wrong.

The table section where the error occurs looks like this:

| Place_Old | Place_New | ### | ### | ### | Region | ### | Continent | ### | ### | ### | Source | ### | ### |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hexheimensis | Herxheim |  |  |  |  |  | Europe |  |  |  | Universitätsmatrikeln |  |  |
| Heydesheim | Heidesheim (Ingelheim am Rhein) |  |  |  |  |  | Europe |  |  |  | Universitätsmatrikeln |  |  |
| Heydesheimensis | Heidesheim (Ingelheim am Rhein) |  |  |  |  |  | Europe |  |  |  | Universitätsmatrikeln |  |  |
| Heydingfeldensis | Heidingsfeld |  |  |  |  |  | Europe |  |  |  | Universitätsmatrikeln |  |  |
| Heydingsfeldensis | Heidingsfeld |  |  |  |  |  | Europe |  |  |  | Universitätsmatrikeln |  |  |
| Heymighausanus | Heiminghausen |  | Geschichtliches aus dem Sau-erland (rjsasse.de) |  |  |  | Europe |  |  |  | Universitätsmatrikeln |  |  |

We are geocoding "Places_New" and "Continent" as "[place name], [continent]". Herxheim is the last place captured. We first thought that the brackets might be an issue, but other data have brackets, too, and Google geocoded them without triggering any errors.

The API is accessed via a Python script we run in Google Colab.